# Understanding the sobel operation output for creating an energy map

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I attempted the [sobel](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html) operation with [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html) to calculate the image gradient. The gradient in both `x` and `y` for the following image:

[image]

was output as follows:

[image]

using the simple code:

```
    sobelXY = cv2.Sobel(image, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 1, ksize=5)
```

It appears that the value in / around white pixels in the output image is less than the value in / around black pixels. For example:

```
sobelXY[20][50] ~= 0
```

but

```
sobelXY[100][700] ~= -150
```

I want to create an energy map of this image where I could identify high change and low change. Currently if I take the Sobel of the image and check the value at the corresponding pixels, I cannot make sense. This is because where the change is high (represented by white) the value of gradient there is less than zero as opposed to greater or close to zero where the change is low (or no change)

Comment: Note that you are computing a 2nd order derivative there: d^2/dxdy. Also, what is white or black depends on the way you display the image. Likely there was some clipping or wrapping of pixel values involved.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I just pass it through the sobel function and print the output to see the values. What could I do here? I want to calculate the gradient of the image in both x and y. Is there a different way you could suggest?

Comment: You need to call `Sobel` twice, once for each derivative.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Is it different from calling `Sobel` once with `dx=1` and `dy=1`?

Comment: Yes, you need to do `cv2.Sobel(image, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0)` and `cv2.Sobel(image, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1)`, to get the two components of the gradient vector.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It will be helpful if you could also share how is it different from a single call with dx=1 and dy=1

Comment: One big obvious difference is that you get two images out, instead of one. One output is the 1st order derivative along the x axis, the other is the 1st order derivative along the y axis. Your result is the 2nd order cross derivative.

Comment: The magnitude of the gradient (square root or the sum of the squares of the two first order derivatives) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: There is a difference between the gradient and derivatives in the x and in the y directions. The gradient is the square root of the sum of the squares of the x and y first derivatives. It will have one polarity -- white edges on black background. The derivatives can be positive or negative. The derivative measure the height of the step at the transitions between light and dark in the image in x and in y. The step ups are positive and step downs are negative. The values depend upon the difference in gray level at the step.

Comment: See  See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html.

Comment: @fmw42: the gradient is a vector. You are describing the magnitude of the gradient, not the gradient itself.

Comment: `@ Cris Luengo`  You are correct. I was trying to explain the different between the gradient magnitude and the x and y directional derivatives. I was a bit too sloppy. The gradient is a vector made up of the first derivatives in the x and y directions. But it was not clear to me what the user was trying to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

Given an image with pixel values within range `[0,255]`, the Sobel operator's output can be within range `[-255,255]`. Therefore, You would need to normalize your Sobel output. You can do this using the norm min_max method.

```
sobelXY = cv2.normalize(sobelXY, 
                dst = sobelXY, 
                alpha = 0, 
                beta = 1, 
                norm_type = cv2.NORM_MINMAX, 
                dtype = cv2.CV_32F)
```

This will normalize your input so that values are between [alpha, beta]

Comment: I want the darker pixels to have low value as compared to the white pixels. Is there a way I could do this?

Comment: This normalization I think will do that. Did you try and see the output?

Comment: Gives the same output

Comment: Did you try assigning the return of the function to sobelXY? look at my updated code

Comment: Yes, I did.But the still the values of darker pixels are more as compared to the white pixels. Is there something we could do?

Comment: @Amanda, what do you mean darker pixels are more compared to white pixels? The gradient is the measure of the change in intensity, so the gradient at a given pixel value would depend on the other pixels around it.

Comment: I meant the gradient at dark pixels stand at 0 and gradient at white pixels are less than 0. Is there a way to reverse this?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I meant the same thing. White pixels (gradient) have a value less than zero and dark pixels (gradient) have very close to zero. Is there some way, I could reverse this? Is there some I could represent the gradient matrix, where dark pixels (non changing pixels) always have lower value than white pixels (high change)?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Have updated my question. Could you please check now?